# Geometry and linear question

Tags: geometry

Given $\theta \in (0, \pi/2)$

There are two lines, $y = (2-\sqrt3)x$ and $y = (\sqrt3 - 2)x$, Find $\theta$ between 2 lines form in $xy$ plane

Comment: What is $\theta$?

Comment: What is the relation between those lines and $\;\theta\;$ ? What must be found?

Answer (score 0):

For $y=mx$, $m=tan(\theta)$ 
$\therefore$
$\theta =2\arctan(2-\sqrt{3} )$ by symmetry

Comment: How can you tell what the question is?!

Comment: I can't but I expect it's the angle between the lines

Comment: Then it isn't an answer, but suitable for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you ask about the angle between the lines:
$$
\theta=\arctan (2-\sqrt3)-\arctan (\sqrt3-2)=2\arctan(2-\sqrt3)=\frac\pi {6}.$$

The last equality can be obtained as follows:
$$
\tan\theta=\frac {2\tan\frac\theta2}{1-\tan^2\frac\theta2}=\frac {2(2-\sqrt3)}{1-(2-\sqrt3)^2}=\frac1 {\sqrt3}.$$

Comment: $$2-\sqrt3=\csc30^\circ-\cot30^\circ=\tan15^\circ$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\theta$ is the angle between the two lines. Then

$$ \tan\theta=\left|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\right|$$

where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the slopes of the two lines.

Comment: so the answer is $\pi/6$?

Comment: Yes, if $\theta$ is the angle between the two lines.

Answer (score 0):

$$arctan(2-\sqrt{3})=15\deg $$
$$arctan(\sqrt{3}-2)=-15\deg $$

The angles are on opposite sides of the $x$-axis so $\theta=30\deg=\frac{\pi}{6}$

Comment: Can someone tell me why I was downvoted?